# What does としたほか mean in this context?

Tags: grammar, translation

What does としたほか mean in this context?

> また、農産品については、ＴＰＰ＝環太平洋パートナーシップ協定など、過去の協定の水準を上回る関税の引き下げは行わないという日本の立場をアメリカが**尊重するとしたほか**、交渉中はアメリカによる自動車への追加関税の発動を回避することを確認したと述べました。

Comment: Hello! What did you find out so far? You need to show research effort and tell us why it wasn't what you were looking for. Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to divide `としたほか` into two parts.

また、農産品については、ＴＰＰ＝環太平洋パートナーシップ協定など、過去の協定の水準を上回る関税の引き下げは行わないという日本の立場をアメリカが`尊重するとした`**ほか**、交渉中はアメリカによる自動車への追加関税の発動を回避することを確認したと述べました。

You should read the `とした` part with `尊重する`, which gives you `尊重するとした`. It means `Someone decided to respect ...` And `とした`here equals to `decided to...`

On the other hand, `ほか` means `besides/In addition to..`

Therefore, `尊重するとしたほか` means `In addition to the fact that they decided to respect ...`